# ASP.NET - System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I created a project in my laptop and it was working fine.

I transferred my project to another laptop and now it gives me a `System.NullReferenceException` error.

Somehow, the database doesn't establishes, it gives a NULL exception.

My code:

```
public partial class registration : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
             // error is here
             SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["registerationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

             conn.Open();
             string chekuser = "select count(*) from userdata where uname='" + TextBoxUN.Text + "'";
             SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(chekuser, conn);
             int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
             if (temp == 1)
             {
                 Response.Write("User already Exist: ");
             }
             conn.Close();                
        }
    }
}
```

WEB.CONFIG

```
<configuration>

  <appSettings/>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>

    <httpRuntime/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Where is the exception thrown, at what line exactly? You are probably missing the corresponding config with the connection strings.

Comment: @DavidPine I don't know where. I am really new to ASP.NET and I don't know anything about it. Can you tell me a way to setup a database connection so that my rest of the code works fine?

Comment: I answered the question

Comment: *I don't know where. I am really new to ASP.NET and I don't know anything about it* - Even if you are new to anything, this is a common exception and you should, by debugging code, be able to detect the line that throws it.

Comment: @OBJ You need to add connection string to your web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Since the error is occuring on this line:

```
SqlConnection conn = 
    new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
                                          ["registerationConnectionString"]
                                          .ConnectionString);
```

You should assume that the `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` is null, and look for your configuration file that was probably not correctly copied over. When you attempt the `.ConnectionString` from the index accessor of the `.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` it returns `null` as you have not configured one in your `web.config`. Look in `web.config` for the [`connectionStrings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233(v=vs.85).aspx) portion.

**Update**

Since you have provided the `web.config` simply add the `connectionStrings` as desired:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
   <add name="registerationConnectionString" 
        connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings/>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>    
    <httpRuntime/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: My web.config file is empty. I have added my Web.config in my question.

Comment: Thank you, but now it gives me a network error on line `Conn.open();`

Comment: That is a different SO question my friend. You need to ensure that you can connect to that server, I usually test this in SSMS first. But the network error means that you're past the `null` exception error. I appreciate upvote and accepted answer. :P See this link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2008/04/30/steps-to-troubleshoot-sql-connectivity-issues/

Comment: But my project is still not resolved. If you please resolve my network path error, I would highly appreciate it. I have to submit my project in an hour.

Comment: You need to fix the network issue, where are you connecting to?

Comment: I am connecting to my local server.

Comment: Try this as a connection string `"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;"`

Comment: I updated my answer with the local connection string, you'll need to change the DBNAME

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any connection string at web.config file with name = `registerationConnectionString` thus `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["registerationConnectionString"]` gives us null value and then when we want to get `ConnectionString` of  null, it gives us `System.NullReferenceException`. You can resolve this by adding following portion in web.config.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="registerationConnectionString" 
       connectionString="Data Source=YourServerName;
         Initial Catalog=YourDatabaseName;
         Persist Security Info=True;
         User ID=yourUserId;
         Password=yourPassword" />
</connectionStrings>
```